# jQuery regex replace and switch around

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to make a jQuery replace function, but just can't seem to figure it out. Regex is not my strong suit. Hopefully someone here can help.

**I need to change the following:**

http://localhost/webshop/page/2/?_categories=music

**to:**

http://localhost/webshop/?_categories=music&_paged=2

**So far this is what i have:**

```
string.replace(/\/page\/([0-9].*?)\//, /&_paged=$1/);
```

**which just produces:**

http://localhost/webshop/&_paged=2/?_categories=music

I need some kind of before and after anchors to switch things around. I have tried all kinds of configurations but just can't figure it out. I read all kinds of posts but can't wrap my head around all those dashes and symbols. Any regex experts out there? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have multiple groups in your regex. Just use them. You were almost there

```
'http://localhost/webshop/page/2/?_categories=music'
   .replace(/^(.+\/webshop)\/page\/(\d+)\/(.+)$/, '$1/$3&_paged=$2')
```

This will produce the exact string you were looking for - http://localhost/webshop/?_categories=music&_paged=2

Comment: Hey thanks a lot ! Problem solved :) I changed it to .replace(/^(.+)\/page\/(\d+)\/(.+)$/, '$1/$3&_paged=$2') to make it work when the path is not webshop.

Comment: Just to understand what is going on. Is the d+ because it is a digit?

Comment: also, I wouldn't mind if you selected my answer as correct! :D I need some of those points! :D fighting with my girlfriend now on who can get more! :D